# json webservice from iphone/ipad

Tags: iphone, objective-c, web-services, json, ipad

Can one help me with this how to consume json web service from iphone or ipad. here my requirement is implement json webservice using API keys...

if possible post some tutorials or example links.....

thanks.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[here is a link for a tutorial for consuming JSON web services from an iPhone app.](http://mobileorchard.com/tutorial-json-over-http-on-the-iphone/)

Answer (score 3):

The canonical JSON processing library is [here](https://github.com/stig/json-framework/), and was written by the Stig Brautaset. Stig's around SO and occasionally pops into obj-c-json discussions.

Comment: Here's another vote for SBJSON. Great library making everything easy.

Answer (score 2):

Check this out. Shows JSON used with Flickr API's on a native app:

http://iosdevelopertips.com/networking/iphone-json-flickr-tutorial-part-1.html

Its a 3 part tutorial and links to the other parts are seen as you scroll to the bottom in the above link. They also have general JSON framework tutorials as well in two parts. Links again can be found in the above page itself. Very useful and pretty much helped me complete all the JSON stuff in my app. Project code is also available for download.

Answer (score 0):

very simple example for GET request the :
download and import AFJSONRequestOperation class.

```
NSURL *myUrl = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"your Url Here"]];
NSLog(@"url is --%@",myUrl);


NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:myUrl];
AFJSONRequestOperation *operation;

operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request
                                                            success:^(NSURLRequest *req, NSHTTPURLResponse *responce, id jsonObject) {




                                                                    NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = [jsonObject objectForKey:@"Enter your key here that has some data"];




                                                            }
                                                            failure:^(NSURLRequest *req, NSHTTPURLResponse *responce, NSError *error, id jsonObject) {
                                                                NSLog(@"Recieved an HTTP %d", responce.statusCode);
                                                                NSLog(@"The error was: %@",error);
                                                            }];
[operation start];
```