# Working with Json Response in Restkit (iPhone)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data, restkit

I have a Json Response like this.

```
{
    "ss": 1,
    "tc": 75,
    "pn": "1",
    "users": [
        {
            "id": "123456",
            "ne": "John Smith",
            "el": "example@example.com"
        },
       {
            "id": "3213243",
            "ne": "iPhone Guy",
            "el": "sdads@dsss.com"
        }
]
}
```

Code:

```
[manager loadObjectsAtResourcePath:@"path/to/resources" usingBlock:^(RKObjectLoader* loader) {


        loader.method = RKRequestMethodPOST;
        loader.params = inputDict;

        loader.onDidLoadResponse  = ^(RKResponse *response)
        {

            NSLog(@"Response is %@",response);// here it contains ss value

        };
        loader.onDidLoadObjectsDictionary = ^(NSDictionary *dictionary)
        {
           // NSLog(@"Dictionary is %@",dictionary);

        };
        loader.onDidFailWithError = ^(NSError *error)
        {
            NSLog(@"Restkit Error is %@",error);  
        };
        loader.onDidLoadObjects = ^(NSArray * objects)
        {
           NSLog(@"Object Count is %d",[objects count]);

        };
    }];
```

From that above response, i would like to check if the success(ss) is 0 or 1. if it is 0, i don't need to map users else i want to map users. how can i do that. Do i need to map ss,tc and pn or is it possible to check ss value w/o mapping.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "mapping"?

Comment: Actually i created NSManagedObject Class using core data model for users. here i am assignin users value to its attributes(mapping). but i want to map if ss is 1, else i don't want to map

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution

```
#import <RestKit/RKJSONParserJSONKit.h>

RKJSONParserJSONKit *parser = [RKJSONParserJSONKit new];
NSDictionary *ditVal = [parser objectFromString:[response bodyAsString] error:nil];
```

the dictionary value contains value and key. from that i can get the value of ss.

Answer (score 0):

i dont know if i am wrong again.
See this if it helps : [json webservice from iphone/ipad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4202038/json-webservice-from-iphone-ipad)

Comment: sorry. i am implementing in objective c for iphone. i mentioned in my tags

Comment: i am using object mapping and all. so Restkit framework would be good one. i think restkit can do that. but i don't know the exact way

Comment: let me search it a bit and i will try to help you.

Comment: i found the answer by myself. Thanks for ur help. i already posted it as an answer

Comment: Good job m8 :D gl with your project!